# Unable to resolve ./Reducers react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm following the following tutorial:
https://medium.com/react-native-training/tutorial-react-native-redux-native-mobile-app-for-tracking-cryptocurrency-bitcoin-litecoin-810850cf8acc

When I run my app, I get the following error message:

> Unable to resolve ./Reducers" from
>   "./C:\Users\Bryan\Documents\React-native\AwesomeProject\src\Store.js`:
>   could not resolve`
>   C:\Users\Bryan\Documents\React-native\AwesomeProject\src\Reducers'
>   as a file nor as a
>   folder","name":"UnableToResolveError","type":"UnableToResolveError","errors":[{}]},"type":"bundling_error"}"

Here Is my Store.js

```
import { Platform } from 'react-native';
import {
    createStore,
    applyMiddleware,
    compose
} from 'redux';
import devTools from 'remote-redux-devtools';
import promise from 'redux-promise';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import logger from 'redux-logger';

import RootReducer from './Reducers';

const middleware = applyMiddleware(thunk, promise, logger);

const Store = createStore (
    RootReducer,
    compose(
        middleware,
        devTools({
            name: Platform.OS,
            hostname: 'localhost',
            port: 5678
        }),
    )
);

export default Store;
```

And in my Reducers-folder, I have the following files:

CryptoReducer.js

```
export default function(state = [], action) {
    return state;
}
```

Index.js

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import CryptoReducer from './CryptoReducer.js';

export default combineReducers({
    crypto: CryptoReducer
});
```

Why do I get this error? Why is it not working and how can I to solve this?

Comment: can you provide you folders/files structure, to see, in which folders these files are located?

Comment: check if your file name is reducer or reducers. or check if you have exported your reducer.